# XML: Unable to validate "type" definition

Tags: php, xml, xml-validation

I am trying to validate XML I generate from my script against an .xsd schema file with PHP 5.3.15 on OSX using `DOMDocument::schemaValidate()`, but it fails to validate `type` definition. I have tried changing it to `xsi:type`, but it still fails. My XML looks *identical* to the XML file that validates without any issues. I am at loss of what could be happening here....

Here is the XML, which it fails to validate:

```
<DataGroups>
    <DataGroup xsi:type="ReportDataGroup"/>

    <DataGroup xsi:type="AlertDataGroup">
      // some XML here
    </DataGroup>

    <DataGroup xsi:type="MetricGroupingDataGroup">
      // some XML here
    </DataGroup>
</DataGroups>
```

I get 1 of the following warnings for each `DataGroup`:

```
Severity: Warning
Message:  DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element 'DataGroup': The type definition is abstract.
```

Or, more specifically

```
Error 1876: Element 'DataGroup': The type definition is abstract
```

I looked up the error. It is:

```
XML_SCHEMAV_CVC_TYPE_2 = 1876 : 1876
```

Here is the relevant part of the .xsd file:

```
<xs:complexType name="DataGroupType" abstract="true"/>

<xs:complexType name="AlertDataGroup">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="DataGroupType">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="AlertBase" type="BaseAlertType"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ReportDataGroup">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="DataGroupType">
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="SmartReportTemplate" type="SmartReportTemplateType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="MetricGroupingDataGroup">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="DataGroupType">
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="MetricGrouping" type="MetricGroupingType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Any idea what could be happening here? I spent all day trying to troubleshoot it, to no avail.
I have to make it validate, or the application on the other end will not read the file, since it validates on load.

**UPDATE:**

I did a side-by-side diff of my generated XML and pre-exiting file that validates just fine. Can not see any differences at all. I have also found a few XML validation services and tools that are able to validate against given schema. Every single one validated it perfectly without any errors. So I do not understand why my local validation still fails.

I am settings correct namespaces:

```
$xml->documentElement->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:introscope', 'generated://introscope.xsd');
$xml->documentElement->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$xml->documentElement->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation', 'http://example.com/path/to/schema.xsd');
```

And my root node looks like it is identical to the one from the file that validates, with all Name spaces set correctly:

```
<ManagementModule xmlns:introscope="generated://introscope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="1.0" Editable="true" DescriptionContentType="text/plain" IsActive="true" Name="ManagementModuleName" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://example.com/path/to/schema.xsd">
```

**UPDATE #2:**

Whoa... After 2 days of this issue I realized that it only fails when try to validate a stream. If i save my XML to a file and try to validate that, it works fine! What?

**UPDATE #3:**

Adding code snippets as requested:

Here is validation code. This snippet is floating on internet and multiple people use it successfully:

```
    function libxml_display_error($error)
    {
        $return = "\n";
        switch ($error->level) {
            case LIBXML_ERR_WARNING:
                $return .= "Warning $error->code: ";
                break;
            case LIBXML_ERR_ERROR:
                $return .= "Error $error->code: ";
                break;
            case LIBXML_ERR_FATAL:
                $return .= "<b>Fatal Error $error->code: ";
                break;
        }
        $return .= trim($error->message);
        if ($error->file) {
            $return .=    " in $error->file";
        }
        $return .= " on line $error->line\n";

        return $return;
    }

    function libxml_display_errors() {
        $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            print libxml_display_error($error);
        }
        libxml_clear_errors();
    }
```

Validation code here. Obviously I run it after xml has been constructed, but I put here here for clarity:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

if (!$xml->schemaValidate('/local/path/to/schema.xsd')) {
    print '<b>DOMDocument::schemaValidate() Generated Errors!</b>';
    libxml_display_errors();

} else {
    echo "VALID XML";
}
```

If I construct my XML like this, it does not validate:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml = Array2XML::createXML('ManagementModule', $json);

$xml->documentElement->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:introscope', 'generated://introscope.xsd');
$xml->documentElement->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$xml->documentElement->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation', 'http://example.com/path/to/schema.xsd');
```

And I receive following errors:

```
Error 1876: Element 'DataGroup': The type definition is abstract. on line 0
Error 1876: Element 'DataGroup': The type definition is abstract. on line 0
Error 1876: Element 'DataGroup': The type definition is abstract. on line 0
```

If I add following line to the above code, save the output to a file called `text.xml`

```
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Then do the following:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('/path/to/test.xml');
```

And then try to validate, I get

```
VALID XML
```

Comment: Please add the two code-examples where it fails (Stream) and works (File). This should make it easier for others identifying your issue.

Comment: validation code snippets have been added!

Comment: Probably because you add the elements. Have you tried `$xml->loadXML($xml->saveXML());`? Just for a test?

Comment: Aaaaand that was it! hakre, you are awesome. please post above comment as an answer, so I can mark it as the solution!

Comment: Not so fast, let's try another one ;) . Instead of the load/save combo, this time let's try `$xml->normalizeDocument();` (the manual page is: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.normalizedocument.php). I'm curious if it does the same good as well ;)

Comment: Nope, `$xml->normalizeDocument();` did not have any affect. Tried inserting it before and after `$xml->saveXML();`. The original one is definitely the winner